# Intellisense not inserting when I press enter in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

When I type I get the usual suggestion from Intellisense,

[image]

but when I press enter or space bar to select (as I always have done), I get this

[image]

Been looking for info on this for a couple of hours now :/ 
I am using Visual Studio 2017 - Community Edition with the latest ReSharper

Comment: You need to use combination of `ctrl + spacebar` to get intellisense in visual studio, **not** enter or spacebar

Comment: You have probably hit `Ctrl+Alt+Space` by accident which is the default shortcut for `Intellisense -> Toggle Completion Mode`

Comment: Meaning?? Can you describe the usage?

Comment: That changes the behavior of the completion mode. I suggest you try out what happens if you change it.

Comment: I have tried ctrl-alt-space bar  ...no result

Comment: When I write something like "public" in a class for a methods, it works as it always have :/

Comment: Maybe navigate to that menu item, because you might have other key bindings. See: `Edit->Intellisense->Toggle Completion Mode`

Comment: Have tried to change Toggle Completion Mode from Edit, not changing anything

Comment: Then perhaps Resharper interferes with it, but I don't use Resharper, so I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: Well, this was my tought as well. Been using ReSharper for a few years now and love it. This has worked before..no updates or anything

Comment: Ok, now I have uninstalled ReSharper...the problem was there. Intellisense working again, now trying to re-install and see what happens

Comment: Yeah, check  _Extensions_ -> _ReSharper_ -> _Options_: **IntelliSense** -> **Completion Behavior**.  If that doesn't point you in the right direction, look for a `*.sln.DotSettings.user` in your solution directory - maybe there's a solution-level override in-place (in which case, removing that file then reloading the solution might get you back to "normal" :)

Comment: Reinstalled ReSharper, everything works great again :)

Answer (score 0):

The promlem was the ReSharper. Propebly caused by some settings I could not find. Re-installed the ReSharper, problem solved